# Visualisation of Compact Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology

How can I visualise a compact metric space?

It is a space of which every infinite open cover has a finite subcover. If I try to imagine finitely many open balls covering a space wholly, it seems to me as if some parts of the balls are outside! (I know this sounds ridiculous...)

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to say that you imagine this like that

[image]

?

[image]

Mm-m-m... You can imagine it as a space where each sequence has a convergent subsequence as well...

Comment: Yes; my teacher tells that there is nothing outside the space but I can not stop myself imagining open balls like that. I also tried to imagine a Compact Space as the surface of a sphere,but nay, another teacher told me that Cantor Set is also compact and has nothing to do with a surface.